# WPF DependencyPropeprty

Tags: wpf, properties, dependencies

I am a beginner.  This question is regarding what is construed from the following link regarding local value resolution of dependency property

http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html

It is explained in the "The magic behind it" section within the webpage pointed to by this link that local value, if exists, is resolved by using a key against a dictionary which lives as a static dictionary within the control.  A key in the dictionary is unique per type (e.g., button).  Please correct me if I am wrong, but to my understanding, there are two dictionaries, one with the key and the "metadata that contain callbacks and a default value" and another with the key and the value of the property.

For the sake of better explaining my question, let's assume then that we have WPF application with two buttons and the Dependency Property in question is "Background". In that case, if both of those buttons have two different backgrounds which are set as local value, we should end up with one Key/value in the first dictionary (key and metadata), and two key/value in the second dictionary (where the background values are stored).  And here comes my question, if the key "must be unique per type", then how could we get in the second dictionary two different keys, each of which with distinct background value, corresponding to the two buttons ?  That is, don't both buttons have the same key as the key is unique per type (i.e., both buttons have the same type)?

Can someone tell me where is the confusion ?

Comment: Why don't you just take a look at the sources? Get e.g. JetBrains dotPeek and inspect the framework assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

There are many dictionaries, not just two. Not all are dictionaries. Mainly they are HashSets. The top most dictionary has a key value pair with the key unique per control type and value unique per defintion. Inside that value all maintainings are happening. Dependency properties are pretty smart and fast for example if you have 100 buttons all with same color there will be only one background color stored under the hood. Its pretty comlicated and like Clemens already suggested to you maybe you should inspect the framework if you want to know more. If you new to wpf then dont do that. Just use it as it is and once its not working post a question here. DPs under the hood nothing for a newbie. It takes alot of wpf knowledge to understand why DPs are implemented the way they are.